# Opening files with extension *.dan *.ix

Tags: database, format, dos

I have a problem with an old database from a dos applocation. There are many files with extensions like .DAN and .IX . I need to import it into my MySQL database. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: I've never even HEARD of that. And my name is even Dan. You'd think. Anyway, I can't even find anything about it anywhere. What application created these? What does the file look like? Is the DAN file a plaintext file, or some binary format?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that It's partially binary or coded in some kind of format I can't recognize. From all that I could find out It's some kind of a pascal database engine. DAN files have data and IX files have indexes. The files have some finantial data, if i open the file in mcedit or any similar editor i can read the names and surnames of people (except some names with polish letters like ą or ł). That would suggest its not in a binary format but any other data is corrupted and i can't see EOL or any other marker that would suggest a new row.

Comment: It could be a binary format that leaves ASCII strings as-is. There may be a string length indicator before the string, or it could be a fixed-width field. A hex editor is going to be your best friend for data recovery here since most numbers and fields will not be converted to strings before being stored. At any rate, try and get a full row of data (incl. all columns) from one of the tables, and possibly a description of the columns' data types, and see if you can reverse engineer the format from that.

Comment: it is a dtSearch index file for text searches. used in the M-files document management system